# Авторские слова — отдельное предложение внутри прямой речи. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Как расставить знаки препинания и с какой буквы начинаются авторские слова?

У Розенталя есть такое правило:
*Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы:
— Скорей, загорелась школа!  — И он побежал по домам будить людей.*

Если же прямая речь продолжается после слов автора, то тоже работает это правило и тогда нужно так оформить следующие предложения?

1.
— Мой папа уже совершенно немолод. И он терпеть не может сериалы, а уж тем более… — Он многозначительно поднял палец вверх. — Тем более зарубежные.

2.
— Вы предложили сыграть роль не в спектакле, а в событии, к которому готовитесь настолько… — Он на секунду замер и показал в воздухе что-то абстрактное и очень большое. — Настолько невероятно!

Answer (score 3):

Считаю, что прямая речь оформлена правильно.

Если на месте разрыва должно было стоять многоточие, то этот знак сохраняется перед авторскими словами, затем ставится тире.
Слова автора (самостоятельное предложение без слов "говорения") начинаются с прописной буквы и заканчиваются точкой; снова ставится тире.
Продолжение прямой речи идет с большой буквы.

• В. Шукшин. Печки-лавочки:
*— Ах, так? Ну погоди... — **И** он пошел из купе, но в дверях еще оглянулся. — **С**час ты у меня уедешь. — И вышел.*

• Вадим Громов. Компромат для олигарха:
*— Но согласитесь: едва ли этого достаточно, чтобы тащить подростка в... — **О**н запнулся. («Надо выразиться поизящнее — ведь она здесь работает!») — **В** ваше заведение.*

• А вот пример с разными пунктуационными особенностями (Рекс Стаут. Лига запуганных мужчин):
*— И... и вы ее открыли! Видимо, вы... —  **О**н замолчал и стоял молча. Голос отказал ему, но я не заметил, чтобы на его лице отразилось какое-либо движение мысли, хотя бы даже неудовольствие. — **В** таком случае... — **п**родолжал он, — **о**на мне не нужна. Не хочу  даже видеть ее.*

[Слова автора внутри прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158) (п. 5)